# Create a spawn shell in Makefile

Tags: linux, shell, makefile, spawn, python-poetry

I want to create a makefile target in Ubuntun to spawn a `poetry shell`. Here are the things I want to do if I were in the command shell:

1. type `poetry shell`, which is going to spawn a shell within the virtual environment.
2. do something in the poetry shell, such as executing a python script using command `python ...`

To facilitate the process, I want to create a makefile looking something like below

```
# if I can set SHELL in a specific way
# SHELL = ?????
foo:
    poetry shell
    echo "Success"
    # many lines to be executed in the poetry shell, here is an example
    python <a_python_file>
```

The problem as I found is that the execution will be hanging after `poetry shell` and will not execute `echo "Success"`

I know this could be a general question on spawning a shell from command shell, and it is not limited to `poetry`. Any comments/suggestions would be appreciated.

---

As a comment pointed out, what I really want is `python ...` instead of `poetry run python ...`. I edited it.

As a comment pointed out, I added some pseudo code in the `makefile`.

Comment: I am thinking adding something in `makefile` like `SHELL = ????`

Comment: If you use `poetry run` you don't need to spawn a new shell via `poetry shell` before.

Comment: @finswimmer oh, sorry, I really mean `python ...`. I use `poetry` to manage my python dependencies. I will edit it.

Comment: I don't understand.  Where is the `python` command you want to run?  It doesn't appear in your makefile anywhere.  Are you expecting to be able to type it in interactively?

Comment: @MadScientist, I did not include the python command as the execution hung after `poetry shell`. If you suggest, I can add `python <a_python_file>` at the end.

Comment: @MadScientist, I want to re-clarify that what I really want is to set the SHELL to `poetry shell`, so that when I execute `python` it can pick up dependencies installed by `poetry`. Sorry for the miscommunication.

Answer (score 3):

I think there's some misunderstanding.  I'd never heard of poetry before but a quick look at its manual makes clear how it works.

If you run `poetry shell` then you get an *interactive shell* which you are expected to type commands into from your keyboard.  The reason it "hangs" is that it started a poetry shell and is now waiting for you to enter commands.  It's not hung, it's waiting for some input.

You don't want to run an interactive set of poetry commands, you have a predefined set of poetry commands you want to run.  For that, you would use `poetry run` as mentioned in the comments above:

```
foo:
    poetry run python <first command>
    poetry run python <second command>
      ...
    echo "Success"
```

If you want to run all the commands within a single instance of poetry, you have to combine them all into a single invocation, maybe something like this (I didn't try this so the quoting might be wrong):

```
foo:
    poetry run 'python <first command> && python <second command> ...'
    echo "Success"
```

You could do this:

```
foo:
        poetry run $(MAKE) in-poetry
        echo "Success"

in-poetry:
        python <command1>
        python <command2>
```

Now if you run `make foo` all the commands in the `in-poetry` target are run within the poetry environment, because `poetry run` runs a make program in its environment, and that make program runs a bunch of python.

But if someone ran `make in-poetry` directory (not via the `foo` target) then those python operations would *not* be run inside a poetry environment (unless the user set it up before they ran `make`).

Comment: I was aware of the option `poetry run` and thanks for spending time in composing this answer. I was naively thinking at a high-level that maybe it is doable that I first set up the `poetry shell` in makefile and then execute more commands as if I were doing them in the interactive terminal. Is it possible that I can make it non-interactive?

Comment: Another reason that I do not want to use `poetry run` (maybe I should, and have no other options) is that many other codes are assuming `python ...` command in the deployment. Of course, I can change them by switching between `poetry run python` and `python`. I feel it is a bit less elegant than the naive thought in the above comment.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "as if I were doing them in the interactive terminal".  For your makefile if you run `make foo` you'll be in a poetry shell.  You can type any commands you want.  When you type `exit`, you'll exit from the poetry shell and return to the makefile and then you will see the `echo "Success"` run.  During the time `poetry shell` is running you'll be in the poetry environment.  When you type `exit` and leave the poetry shell, you will no longer be in the poetry environment.  There is no way to stay in the poetry environment after the poetry shell finishes.

Comment: If you want to run a whole bunch of make operations from inside the poetry shell what you _can_ do is run make recursively from within `poetry run`.  For example, if you use `foo: ; poetry run $(MAKE) sometarget` then the entire make process, including whatever commands are invoked to satisfy `sometarget` will be inside the poetry environment, until that submake is complete.

Comment: Is it possible after launch of the `poetry shell` to continue executing the rest of the commands in poetry shell?

Comment: That is great. Could you please add a makefile example in the answer to demo "run a whole bunch of make operations from inside the poetry shell"?

Comment: What do you mean by "the rest of the commands"?  In a makefile (or a shell script or anything else), commands are run one at a time.  When the command exits, then the next one runs.  Any environment that was set up in that command is thrown away when it exits.  There's no way for a child process to modify the environment of its parent process.  This is a fundamental feature of the operating system, it doesn't have anything to do with make.

Comment: Right. I mean (am thinking) setting up the `poetry shell` environment before execution,  and afterwards all the commands/targets in the makefile will be executed in the `poetry shell` environment.

Comment: Sure, you can do that if you want but you have to do it before you start `make`.  Or else run a recursive make invocation as I showed.  Make doesn't execute shell scripts in its own process space: it runs a child process, a shell, to do that.  A subprocess must run to completion and exit before make will continue.